# How to include jetbrain rider ide package

Tags: jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-rider

I generally create net core and net core api applications. I just switched to jetbrain rider ide and there is no client side library in vs2022, what solution do you use for this? I could not find an article about npm or a source that has been tried before.I would like to express my gratitude in advance to those who can help.